# Why css and png are not accessible?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have created an Ingress, Deployment and Service as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes-first
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes-first
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes-first
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes-first
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes-first
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-kubernetes
          image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: MESSAGE
              value: Hello from the first deployment!
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
  name: helloworld-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "hw.service.databaker.io"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes-first
              servicePort: 80
---
```

When I call https://hw.service.databaker.io/, it blocks:

[image]

CSS and PNG. What am I doing wrong? I am using Istio 1.52.

The log of one of three pods has following content:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:25:06 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36" 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:33:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.129 Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:34:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.129 Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:34:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.129 Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:34:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.129 Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:34:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.129 Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:36:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.129 Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" 
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020:10:36:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 680 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.129 Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: If you look at the pod's logs, is it receiving the requests via the ingress service?

Comment: Yes, it receives the request. I've updated my post. As you can see on the picture, css and png can not be accessed but the path / works. Maybe wildcard is missing?

Comment: I've got it. The path has to be `path: /*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not accessible because you have to show istio the path to it.

---

As @zero_coding mentioned in comments one way is to change the path

from

```
http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes-first
              servicePort: 80
```

**to**

```
http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes-first
              servicePort: 80
```

---

Additionally I would add this [Istio in practise](https://rinormaloku.com/istio-practice-routing-virtualservices/) tutorial here, it explains well second way of dealing with that problem, which is to add more paths.

> Let’s break down the requests that should be routed to Frontend:
>
> **Exact path** / should be routed to Frontend to get the Index.html
>
> **Prefix path** /static/* should be routed to Frontend to get any static files needed by the frontend, like **Cascading Style Sheets** and **JavaScript files**.
>
> **Paths matching the regex ^.*.(ico|png|jpg)$** should be routed to Frontend as it is an image, that the page needs to show.

```
http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    - uri:
        exact: /callback
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
    route:
    - destination:
        host: frontend             
        port:
          number: 80
```